# Interpolation and points of non-differentiability

Tags: interpolation

I have some data, which if expressed by some elementary functions, would contain a non-differentiable point. I would like to be able to use something like interpolate to convert  the data into a function and then differentiate it but somehow still preserve the non-differentiability property at that point.

MWE

```
list = Table[{j, Max[5, j]}, {j, 0, 15, 1}]

{{0, 5}, {1, 5}, {2, 5}, {3, 5}, {4, 5}, {5, 5}, {6, 6}, {7, 7}, {8, 
  8}, {9, 9}, {10, 10}, {11, 11}, {12, 12}, {13, 13}, {14, 14}, {15, 
  15}}
```

My data comes from a continuous function which is not differentiable at $x=5$.

```
fint = Interpolation[list]

dfint[x_] = D[fint[x], x]

Plot[dfint[x], {x, 0, 15}, AxesOrigin -> {0, -1}]
```

The Derivative looks like this:

[image]

Instead of like this:

[image]

**Update 12:38 AM May 22:**

```
lista = DeleteCases[list, a_ /; a[[1]] >= 6]
listb = DeleteCases[list, a_ /; a[[1]] <= 4]

{{0, 5}, {1, 5}, {2, 5}, {3, 5}, {4, 5}, {5, 5}}

{{5, 5}, {6, 6}, {7, 7}, {8, 8}, {9, 9}, {10, 10}, {11, 11}, {12, 
  12}, {13, 13}, {14, 14}, {15, 15}}

ga = Interpolation[lista]
gb = Interpolation[listb]

dga[x_] = D[ga[x], x]
dgb[x_] = D[gb[x], x]

g[x_] = Piecewise[{{ga[x], x <= 5}, {gb[x], x > 5}}]

dg[x_] = Piecewise[{{dga[x], x < 5}, {dgb[x], x > 5}}]
```

Doing this

```
Plot[dg[x], {x, 0, 15}, AxesOrigin -> {0, -1}]
```

gives

[image]

However

```
dg[5]

0
```

I guess I need to get this to be indeterminate.

Comment: Just do `dg[x_] = D[g[x], x]` and then `dg[5]` automatically becomes indeterminate...

Comment: You could use `Piecewise[]`'s default value; set it to `Indeterminate` instead of `0`.

Comment: @RahulNarain and J.M. great thanks!

Comment: Look also at `InterpolationOrder`.

Comment: @RahulNarain oh, yes, I wasn't focused enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do `dg[x_] = D[g[x], x]` and then `dg[5]` automatically becomes indeterminate.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in a comment, you can use `InterpolationOrder -> 1` and then fix the `Indeterminate` derivative.

```
ClearAll[list, fint, dfint]
list = Table[{j, Max[5, j]}, {j, 0, 15, 1}];
ListLinePlot@list

fint = Interpolation[list, InterpolationOrder -> 1]

Plot[fint[x], {x, 0, 15}, AxesOrigin -> {0, -1}]
dfint[x_] = D[fint[x], x]

Plot[dfint[x], {x, 0, 15}, AxesOrigin -> {0, -1}]
dfint@5
dfint@5 = Indeterminate;
dfint@5
```

It should be easy to come up with an algorithm that automatically sets all the `Indeterminate` derivatives of an `InterpolationOrder -> 1` function...